# Can a mysql transaction be done inside mysql event scheduler?

Tags: mysql, transactions, mysql-event

I want to update 3 tables based on the start date of another table. So i  generate an event scheduler which checks the start date in that table and the current date.. It would be of great help to know if it is possible to create a transaction in an event scheduler

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html says:

> Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, **and events**), the parser treats `BEGIN [WORK]` as the beginning of a `BEGIN ... END` block. Begin a transaction in this context with `START TRANSACTION` instead.

(emphasis mine)

This suggests that you can start and commit transactions within an event. But for syntax parsing reasons, don't start a transaction with `BEGIN`.